# Python: Using recursive methods to get Binary Search Tree Height

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary-search-tree, binary-search

for my assignment, I am trying to get height of the Binary Search Tree through linear time. The prof specified that he wants us to keep track of the height in our recursive insertion and removal methods, yet mine never works during the test.

The prof's requirement is: "Add an attribute to the __Node class to store the height of the subtree rooted at that node. Just before returning a node reference at the end of a recursive call, update that node's height field to be correct."

My thought is, instead of making changes at a root, if the insertion or removal moves down left or right, the height increases/decrease by one (but I'm not sure how it works if there is still something left at level-n).

I have attached my code over here:

```
class Binary_Search_Tree:

  class __BST_Node:

    def __init__(self, value):
      self.value = value
      self.left=None   
      self.right=None
      self.height=0

  def __init__(self):
    self.__root = None  

  def __recur_ins(self, val,root):
    if root is None:
        root = Binary_Search_Tree.__BST_Node(val)
    elif root.value > val:
        root.left = self.__recur_ins(val,root.left) 
        root.height += 1
    elif root.value < val:
        root.right =self. __recur_ins(val,root.right)
        root.height += 1
    return root

  def __get_min(self,node):
    walker=node
    while walker.left is not None:
        walker=walker.left
    return walker

  def __recur_rem(self, val, root):
    if root is None:
        raise ValueError
    if root.value == val:
        if root.left is None:
            cur = root.right
            root = None
            return cur
        elif root.right is None:
            cur = root.left
            root = None
            return cur
        elif (root.left is not None) and (root.right is not None):
            cur = self.__get_min(root.right)
            root.value = cur.value
            root.right = self.__recur_rem(cur.value, root.right)
    elif val < root.value:
        root.left=self.__recur_rem(val,root.left)
        root.height -= 1
    elif val > root.value:
        root.right=self.__recur_rem(val, root.right)
        root.height -= 1
    return root

  def __actual_height(self,bst_node):
    if bst_node is None:
        return 0
    else:
        return self.__root.height

  def get_height(self):
    return self.__actual_height(self.__root)
```

Thank you so much in advance! Any help will be very appreciated!

Comment: why is the interface like this, how is the user supposed to add nodes to the tree?

Comment: @BanishedBot I have public methods for them to add nodes, but I didn't put them up just in case the code gets to long.... Should I put them up as well?

Comment: it's better if you add more code so that other users can run it and potentially find the problem